# Supply response from Spring to Angularjs

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-mvc

I am trying to get the response from the spring controller to Angularjs get request

Here is the java code

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/getEmployee")
    public ResponseEntity<List<EmployeeModel>> getEmployee() {
        System.out.println("get List");
        List<EmployeeModel> em=employeeService.getEmployee();
        return new ResponseEntity<List<EmployeeModel>>(em, HttpStatus.OK);
```

i have the list of `EmployeeModel` in `em` variable

but somehow i am not able to get it in the `data` of angularjs response(`success`)

Here is the angularjs code

```
$scope.listEmployee = function() {
                    $http({
                        method : 'GET',
                        url : '/Employee/getEmployee'
                    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        console.log("data.token " + data);
                    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        console.log("data.token " + data.token);
                    });
                };
```

> browser Status Code:406 Not Acceptable

Please help

Comment: What error you are getting ?

Comment: nothing in the eclipse , but in browser Status Code:406 Not Acceptable

Comment: Ok that means the data you are sending is in unacceptable format . Can you print what you have in controller in that list before you send it ?

Comment: Ok a quick question, are you using Maven to build it ??

Comment: i double checked it and yes i can print it. it is the list of EmployeeModel(as per the expectation)

Comment: yes i am using maven

Comment: See my answer. I hope that worka

Comment: thanks for your attempt . but not working :(

Comment: did it worked , what it is saying ?

Comment: same error >Status Code:406 Not Acceptable

Comment: try annotating ResponseEntity to ResponseBody . And then try.Give it @ResponseBody annotation too.

Comment: tried ... but still same error :(

Comment: Hmm..let me check running some code . Will get back to you

Comment: try my updated answer

Comment: again no luck :( same error :(

Answer (score 0):

Add following lines to your pom.xml
dependency groupId org.codehaus.jackson jackson-mapper-asl 1.7.1

Try adding following all HTTP headers to your request in following manner
HttpHeaders headers= new HttpHeaders(); List medias = new ArrayList(); medias.add(MediaType.ALL); headers.setAccept(medias); 
And add headers as a second argument before sending response 
 . It will ensure data format is acceptable to any kind of accept header .